# Piece of Ruby code is confusing - super

Tags: ruby

I'm reading Zed Shaw's Ruby introduction book. I came across a piece of code I don't quite understand.

```
class Person

def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @pet = nil
end 

attr_accessor :pet
end 

class Employee < Person

def initialize(name, salary)
    super(name)
    @salary = salary
end 

attr_accessor :salary, :name
end
```

I understand the super(name) part very roughly. I believe that means it defers to the parent class? I'm not sure I understand why this would be done in the real world. Why would someone do super(name) rather than just write @name = name?

I'm still learning. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why would someone do super(name) rather than just write `@name = name`?

Let's look from another angle. Why would someone duplicate [potentially complex] functionality, which already exists in parent class, rather than simply delegate the work to parent?

If you duplicate the functionality and then requirements change, you need to go change all of the copies. This is error-prone and needlessly expensive (in terms of time/efforts).

Answer (score 1):

I see two different programming best-practices being used here.

First is the best-practice of never duplicating code. You'll often see code like this:

```
class MyClass

  def blah
    @blah
  end

  def do_something
    puts blah
  end

end
```

You may wonder "why does the programmer call the method `blah()` when they could just use the variable `@blah` instead? The answer is that `@blah` may be a simple variable right now, but what if you decide to save it in a hash later, accessible as `myData[:blah]`? It would be a pain to go through every line of code, searching for every `@blah` and changing it to `myData[:blah]`. Using the method `blah()` ensures that if you ever change the way `@blah` works, you only have to change it in one place: the method.

The same can be said for `super(name)` vs `@name = name`. Right now, the `initialize()` method for `Person` might be simple, but someday it might become really complicated. You wouldn't want to have to change the code of every class inheriting `Person`, so it's best to call `super()`.

---

Second is the best-practice of encapsulation. Imagine for a second that your code looks like this instead:

```
require "person"

class Employee < Person

  def initialize(name, salary)
    super(name)
    @salary = salary
  end 

  attr_accessor :salary, :name
end
```

In object-oriented programming, it's common to use libraries made by other people, with classes and objects that you didn't write and don't have the ability to change.

Encapsulation is the idea that a class is a self-sufficient and independent machine. You pass it input data and receive output data, but you have no idea what's going on inside. So in this code, even though `Employee` inherits `Person`, `Employee` shouldn't make any assumptions about what the `Person` class is doing under the hood. Calling `super(name)` is trusting `Person` to set itself up, without worrying about the details of how a `Person` should be set up.

Even if the two classes are written in the same file and you can see the source code for both, it's important to follow the best practice of encapsulation to keep your code clean and robust for your future self and other programmers, because someday those two classes may be in different files or even different libraries.